# best way to create a numpy array from a list and additional individual values

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I want to create an array from list entries and some additional individual values.

I am using the following approach which seems clumsy:

```
x=[1,2,3]
y=some_variable1
z=some_variable2
x.append(y)
x.append(z)
arr = np.array(x)

#print arr --> [1 2 3 some_variable1 some_variable2]
```

is there a better solution to the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list addition to add the variables all placed in a list to the larger one, like so:

```
arr = np.array(x + [y, z])
```

Comment: Thx, this seems much cleaner than my approach

Answer (score 1):

Appending or concatenating lists is fine, and probably fastest.

Concatenating at the array level works as well

```
In [456]: np.hstack([x,y,z])
Out[456]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

This is compact, but under the covers it does

```
np.concatenate([np.array(x),np.array([y]),np.array([z])])
```